# Extract images from excel in a web application?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, web-applications

When I upload a excel file to the server I want to extract the images in the uploaded file and store them in the root directory. I tried it with the windows application it works fine but does not seem to work for web applications.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(file,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[1];   //Selects the first sheet
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ws.Cells[1, 1];      //Select cell A1
object cellValue = range.Value2;

#region Extract the image
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Picture pic = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Picture)ws.Pictures(1);

if (pic != null)
{
    //This code will detect what the region span of the image was
    int startCol = (int)pic.TopLeftCell.Column;
    int startRow = (int)pic.TopLeftCell.Row;
    int endCol = (int)pic.BottomRightCell.Column;
    int endRow = (int)pic.BottomRightCell.Row;


    pic.CopyPicture(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);
    //From here How to save in the root directory ??
}
#endregion

//Close the workbook
wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

//Exit Excel
excelApp.Quit();
```

This code contains retrieves the image, but I can't figure it out how to save it in the root folder.

I'm open to alternative ways of extracting images from a spread sheet as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of code works for web and for desktop application, extracting the images in a spreadsheet to a folder in the root.

```
//'file' could be a HttpPostedFileBase from client side
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedPO"), fileName);

file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(physicalPath,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing);
Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[1];


var app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = wb;
Excel.Worksheet wsCurrent = ws;
Excel.XlFileFormat format = Excel.XlFileFormat.xlHtml;

wsCurrent.SaveAs(physicalPath, format);

workbook.Close();
```